# Remove Training Parentheses in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I remove the trailing parentheses from this query? The table below shows a few results of what the query outputs. I know I could just export the query into Excel and do it that way, but trying to work more on my SQL queries.

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [DepartmentNumber],
[DepartmentName],
[ChiefID],
[ChiefName],
[ChiefEmail],
[DelegateID],
substring(DelegateName, 1, CHARINDEX('(', DelegateName) - 1) DelegateName,
substring(DelegateName, CHARINDEX('(', DelegateName) + 1, LEN(DelegateName)) Accesss
FROM vwList
```

Edit: Here is the data before I do anything with it.

| DelegateName |
| --- |
| Smith, John M (Upload only) |
| Smith, Christine (Upload only) |
| Smith, Steven M. (View and Upload) |
| Smith, Kevin Lee (View) |

Edit: Results from query

| DelegateName | Access |
| --- | --- |
| Smith, John M | Upload only) |
| Smith, Christine | Upload only) |
| Smith, Steven M. | View and Upload) |
| Smith, Kevin Lee | View) |

Comment: USE REPLACE(access, ')', '')

Comment: When I do REPLACE(Access, ')', ''), I get invalid column name. Do I need to declare the Access column name somehow?

Comment: Rather than showing us the result you're getting, show us the data as it is *before* your failed attempt and the results you want.

Comment: @Larnu - Sorry about that. I've updated my post.

Comment: Now we're missing the expected results.

Comment: @larnu - they are back there

Comment: So is your data always in the format `Surname, First Name {Middle Initial} (Access information)`?

Comment: @Larnu - yes, it's always in that order. Not everyone has a middle initial though

Answer (score 1):

`TRIM` seems appropriate here:

```sql
SELECT LEFT(V.Delegate,CHARINDEX('(',V.Delegate)-2),
       TRIM(')' FROM STUFF(V.Delegate,1,CHARINDEX('(',V.Delegate),''))
FROM (VALUES('Smith, John M (Upload only)'),
            ('Smith, Christine (Upload only)'),
            ('Smith, Steven M. (View and Upload)'),
            ('Smith, Kevin Lee (View)'))V(Delegate);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=913052a92d93f897709ae555eb7b8c79)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have to do this for 200 records. Not just the four in the example. Would there be a better way than listing out all the values individually?

Comment: You would obviously be running the above against your table, @Austin ...

Comment: right, but I'm confused i guess. I'm not understanding how to run that against my table

Comment: Where are you struggling, @Austin ..? YOur table goes in the `FROM`, like you have in your attempt... `SELECT ... FROM vwList` If you're not familiar with the `FROM` clause, you need to read up on the basic of the SQL dialects first.

Comment: I get the from clause. I'm not understanding how to use the TRIM in my query.

Comment: Exactly as it appears in my answer, @Austin ... `TRIM(')' FROM STUFF(V.Delegate,1,CHARINDEX('(',V.Delegate),''))` Apart from replace the column name and alias appropriately. I really don't understand what you don't understand here. Putting an expression is the `SELECT` is also a *very* low level part of SQL. Again, I suggest that perhaps you read some tutorials first, as (with respect) on [so] it is assumed that you have at least fundamental knowledge of the language you are using; you don't appear to.

Answer (score 0):

If you know for certain that the "access" part of the value in DelegateName is wrapped in parenthesis, you can remove the last char from the result,
or, if you know it will contain only one instance of ')', you can replace the closing parenthesis with empty string - as suggested.

```sql
substring(DelegateName, CHARINDEX('(', DelegateName) + 1, LEN(DelegateName)-1) Accesss
```

Comment: Yes. For example, the delegatename is Smith, John M (upload only) or can be Smith, John M (view)